# enumerating loading of a large csv doesn't seem to be evaluated lazily

Tags: python, csv

It's my understanding that enumerate evaluates lazily, since it can be applied to generators, and that a csv.reader is also lazy, however, when combined on a large csv file, they crash my kernel.

This code hangs and eventually crashes my kernel on a very large file:

```
with open(RAW_DATA) as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    data = []
    for row_idx, row in enumerate(csv_reader):
        data.append(row)
        if (row_idx + 1) % BLOCK_SIZE == 0:
            dump_data(data)
            data = []
```

However, this code works perfectly, each loop taking approx 2 seconds:

```
with open(RAW_DATA) as file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    data = []
    row_idx = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        data.append(row)
        row_idx += 1
        if row_idx % BLOCK_SIZE == 0:
            dump_data(data)
            data = []
```

This doesn't make sense to me - I would think that assuming lazy evaluation, they are functionally equivalent?